# Optimized my VBA and error handler is longer returning output

Tags: excel, vba

The error handler stopped producing after Optimizing the VBA code for the faster performer. Please pardon my use of words I am new to VBA and I have also the shorten the length of the code for easy readability.

See the code below.

```
Sub D2dLookup2019()
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      
       
    Set rng = Range("B:B")
    Set rng5 = Range("A:A")
    Set rng2 = Range("G:G")
    Set rng3 = Range("E:E")
    Set rng4 = Range("F:F")
     lookupYear = Array(SValue, "2019")
     lastrow = Sheet11.Range("HS" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     MsgBox lastrow
     
     On Error GoTo MyerrorHandler:
     For i = 4 To lastrow
     
     If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 227).Value) = True Then
     Else
             
     Cells(i, 231) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rng3, rng, Cells(i, 227).Value, rng4, Cells(2, 231).Value, rng5, SValue) / Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rng3, rng, Cells(i, 227).Value, rng5, SValue)
      Cells(i, 231) = Cells(i, 231).Value * Cells(i, 228).Value
      Cells(i, 232) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rng3, rng, Cells(i, 227).Value, rng4, Cells(2, 232).Value, rng5, SValue) / Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rng3, rng, Cells(i, 227).Value, rng5, SValue)
      Cells(i, 232) = Cells(i, 232).Value * Cells(i, 228).Value
         
    End If

    
MyerrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 6 And Cells(i, 227).Value = "CHOICE ENERGY SERVICES RETAIL" Then
          Cells(i, 231) = 0
          Cells(i, 231) = Cells(i, 231).Value * Cells(i, 228).Value
          Cells(i, 232) = 0
        
         
    
End If

Resume Next
Next i

Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Thank you for the assistance

Comment: when you do `Cells(i, 231) = Cells(i, 231).Value * Cells(i, 228).Value` in the error block the value of `Cells(i, 231).Value` is `0` and `0` times anything will always be `0`.  not sure what you are trying here.

Comment: I shortened the code, This is the rest of the error handle code                           
      Cells(i, 237) = 0                          
      Cells(i, 237) = Cells(i, 237).Value * Cells(i, 228).Value
      Cells(i, 238) = 1                                                                                         
      Cells(i, 238) = Cells(i, 238).Value * Cells(i, 228).Value
      Cells(i, 239) = 0

Comment: Your code is rather wonky I'm afraid.  Your error handler code will be run every iteration of the loop whether there is an error or not.  You need at least to move your error handling code outside of the loop to after the exit sub.

Comment: I know this is not the best of VBA code, I am new to VBA, do you mind posting a snippet